# How can I look up buses (and other public transport) in Poland?

Tags: public-transport, europe, buses, poland

In Slovakia, we have this thing called *Cestovné poriadky* (Travel schedules), using which I can look up which scheduled buses I can use to go from some A to some B.

Does something like this exists in Poland and could any of you point me to the right resources?

Answer (score 0):

While not specific to Poland, [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com) does a good job with intra-country transportation.

Comment: Very much a different kind of site from the one OP mentions. I think this does not answer the question, although I will not take action.

Comment: And why won't you take action?

Comment: @chx It's certainly different in that it is not limited to one country, but it does provide information and schedules for intra-Poland travel by bus, and is therefore responsive to the OP's request. Both the OP's cited Slovakia page and Rome2Rio are commercial operations. Why do you think the reference to R2R should be deleted?

Comment: Have you even looked at https://cp.hnonline.sk/vlakbusmhd/spojenie/ before answering?

Comment: @chx Why yes, I did look at it before I commented. But I don't speak or read Slovak, so I was limited to what Google Chrome provided for a translation. What do you see there that I'm missing?

Comment: @chx, I think this answer is not wrong enough to take action.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica _everything_